# Reading order for Bob, Agent of Hydra

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, deadpool, hydra

Bob, Agent of Hydra (aka Hydra Bob) is a minor Hydra extra in the comics who is sometimes a sidekick of Deadpool.

What is the reading order for the comics featuring Hydra Bob?

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Bob_(Hydra_Agent)_(Earth-616)/Appearances